# Filling a series based on key value pairs

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, key-value, missing-data

I have a data frame that includes a dictionary of codes and names.  Some of the names are blank.  I'm trying to fill those blanks based on other examples where the code matches a name.  Thus far I have sorted into a df by code but can't figure out how to "fill in the blanks".  Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
df = pd.read_json('data/world_bank_projects.json')
theme= pd.DataFrame([val for pair in df['mjtheme_namecode'].values for val in pair])
theme1 = theme.set_index('code').sort_index()
print(theme1)

                     name
code                     
1     Economic management
1     Economic management
1     Economic management
1     Economic management
1     Economic management
1     Economic management
1     Economic management
1     Economic management
1     Economic management
1     Economic management
1                        
1     Economic management
1                        
1     Economic management
1     Economic management
1                        
1     Economic management
1     Economic management
1     Economic management
1     Economic management
```

After I fill in I'd like to count (by either code or name which should be the same). I think I could just use value_counts for that, right?